# Parse notification disapear when I open status bar

Tags: android, parse-platform, notifications

I got this bug in some devices like sony xperia Z and wiko.
I did implement Parse notification.I am setting my notification icon in my manifest.xml:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.parse.push.notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

When I receive a notification. My icon will appear in the satatus bar:
[image]
Until now everything is ok.
But when I try to open the status bar to check the message. My notification will appear without the icon. Only the message will appear:
[image]
Did anyone faced the same problem? And any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem , I fixed it by changing my icon image to a 24x24 dp.

[What are the sizes of the icons in Android notifications action-buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454470/what-are-the-sizes-of-the-icons-in-android-notifications-action-buttons)

[Android status bar expects icons of size 25x25dp while guidelines recommend 32x32dp. Who is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265595/android-status-bar-expects-icons-of-size-25x25dp-while-guidelines-recommend-32x3)