# Android Notification Action Icon Sizes in Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-notifications, android-icons

What should be the icon sizes in the notification action (button) for the material design? I am looking for the complete icon sizes (icon bounds/optical bounds).

[image]

I came across a very similar question:

[What are the sizes of the icons in Android notifications action-buttons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454470/what-are-the-sizes-of-the-icons-in-android-notifications-action-buttons)

but that was prior to material design era. On top of that, the selected answer is incomplete since it does not specify the icon sizes(icon bounds/optical bounds) for every device density.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the ActionBar icon size. It will look good.
Or you can generate Generic icon using the following link and use it.
[Icon Generator](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-generic.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&size=24&padding=8&color=33b5e5%2C100&name=ic_example)

Comment: Thanks ch3tanz but like I said, I am looking for the complete icon sizes (icon bounds/optical bounds)..